# Error: Mysql database doesn't support transactions

Tags: mysql, database, benchmarking, workbench

Hi I have a InnoDB has a default database which supports transactions.
But When I run transactions script for Mysql sql-benchmarking I get below error:

```
Testing server 'MySQL 5.5.29 0ubuntu0.12.10.1' at 2013-02-11 11:32:28

Test skipped because the database doesn't support transactions
```

show engines;

```
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

I have edited my.cnf adding default-engine Innodb. but still no luck.

The perl script is "test-transaction" in Mysql Sql bench...

```
###
### Test insert perfomance
###

test_insert("bench1","insert_commit",0);
test_insert("bench2","insert_autocommit",1);

sub test_insert
{
  my ($table, $test_name, $auto_commit)= @_;
  my ($loop_time,$end_time,$id,$rev_id,$grp,$region);

  $dbh->{AutoCommit}= $auto_commit;
  $loop_time=new Benchmark;

  for ($id=0,$rev_id=$opt_loop_count-1 ; $id < $opt_loop_count ;
       $id++,$rev_id--)
  {
    $grp=$id/$opt_groups;
    $region=chr(65+$id%$opt_groups);
    do_query($dbh,"insert into $table values ($id,$rev_id,'$region',$grp,0)");
  }

  $dbh->commit if (!$auto_commit);
  $end_time=new Benchmark;
  print "Time for $test_name  ($opt_loop_count): " .
    timestr(timediff($end_time, $loop_time),"all") . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Is the  Test DB set to the InnoDB engine ?

Comment: Yes it shows InnoDB. But still not sure why it is failing.

Comment: Could this be a permissions problem?

Comment: Are you connecting to the right MySQL instance?

Comment: Could you please show us the script (put here or give us external link)?

Comment: I have added module this is an open source code in Msql Sql bench.

Comment: Ok. Could you do the sanity check. Connect to MySQL using command line. Execute `start transaction; insert into table() values(); commit;`. And see the results. If it will be fine that you should look at testing script rather than searching for issues in MySQL config. Just connect to the same instance/database. Do not forget to post the result here